# Unable to get preview of aspx pages having custom page layout in search in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, publishing-page, owa, preview

We have a publishing site in SharePoint Online which has News Page layout (Custom page layout) associated with default publishing page library.

when we are searching any pages, we are able to get preview of pages having default SharePoint page layout. but we are not able to get preview of pages having custom page layout.

E.g.

default SharePoint page layout:

[image]

custom page layout:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

**Cause:**

When I checked inspect element for custom page layout, i found that it was referring Item_default.js and callback was set for Item_default_hoverpanel.js.

i.e.

> onfocus="EnsureScriptParams('SearchUI.js', 'HP.Show',
>   'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_csr4_item',
>   'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_csr4_hover',
>   '~sitecollection\u002f_catalogs\u002fmasterpage\u002fDisplay
>   Templates\u002fSearch\u002fItem_Default_HoverPanel.js', false);"

And for default webpage it was referring Item_Webpage.js and callback was set for Item_Webpage_hoverpanel.js

i.e.

> onfocus="EnsureScriptParams('SearchUI.js', 'HP.Show',
>   'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_csr2_item',
>   'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_csr2_hover',
>   '~sitecollection\u002f_catalogs\u002fmasterpage\u002fDisplay
>   Templates\u002fSearch\u002fItem_WebPage_HoverPanel.js', false);

**Solution:**

I edited Item_default.html (bcz we cannot edit js file directly) and changed callback to Item_WebPage_HoverPanel.js

i.e. Changed below line of code from Item_default.html

```
<!--#_ 
    if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
        var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
        var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
        var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
        var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default_HoverPanel.js";
        $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
        if(ctx.CurrentItem.IsContainer){
            ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getFolderIconUrl();
        }
        ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
        ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
_#-->
```

to

```
<!--#_ 
    if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
        var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
        var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
        var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
         var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_WebPage_HoverPanel.js";
        $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
        ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
        ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
_#-->
```

And it started working and preview is showing for custom pages. :-)